# Historical Stock Price Quote on delisted stock without knowing stock symbol as of quote date

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing

looking for historical stock closing price (as of 2/20/2006 or last trading date before) for Sierra Pacific Resources which later became NV Energy (NVE) and was purchased by a Berkshire Hathaway sub in 2013. NVE search does not yield any info. can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need a source of delisted historical data.  Such data is typically only available from paid sources.

According to my records 20 Feb 2006 was not a trading day - it was Preisdent's Day and the US exchanges were closed.

The prior trading date to this was 17 Feb 2006 where the stock had the following data:
Open: 14.40
High 14.46
Low 14.16
Close 14.32
Volume 1339800 (consolidated volume)

Source: Symbol NVE-201312 within Premium Data US delisted stocks historical data set available from http://www.premiumdata.net/products/premiumdata/ushistorical.php

Disclosure: I am a co-owner of Norgate / Premium Data.